# '429 error: too many requests' when using Instagram API with Python script

Tags: python, ajax, image, automation, instagram

I am trying to run a script that logs in to Instagram and uploads 10 images that have random text on them that have been generated. However, here is the output I am getting when I try to run the script:

```
2023-01-02 21:56:48,608 - INFO - Instabot version: 0.117.0 Started
Which account do you want to use? (Type number)
1: ACCOUNTNAME
0: add another account.
-1: delete all accounts.
1
2023-01-02 21:56:51,371 - INFO - Not yet logged in starting: PRE-LOGIN FLOW!
2023-01-02 21:56:51,573 - ERROR - Request returns 429 error!
2023-01-02 21:56:51,573 - WARNING - That means 'too many requests'. I'll go to sleep for 5
minutes.
```

How can I fix this issue?

Here is the code I am using:

```py
import random
import requests
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import time
import instabot

# Generate 10 random images
for i in range(10):
  # Create a black image
  image = Image.new('RGB', (500, 500), (0, 0, 0))
  draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

  # Generate a random string of white text
  text = ''.join([
    random.choice(
      'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()_+-=[]{};:\'",.<>/?')
    for i in range(10)
  ])
  # Use a default font with a larger size
  font = ImageFont.truetype('cour.ttf', 72)

  # Randomly position each letter on the image
  x = 0
  y = 0
  for letter in text:
    draw.text((x, y), letter, (255, 255, 255), font=font)
    x += random.randint(30, 50)
    y += random.randint(-10, 10)

  # Save the image and create a corresponding text file
  image.save(f'generated-images/image{i}.jpg')
  with open(f'generated-images/image{i}.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(text)

try:
  # Create an Instabot instance
  bot = instabot.Bot()

  # Login to Instagram
  bot.login()

  # For each image and corresponding text file
  for i in range(10):
    # Open the text file
    with open(f'generated-images/image{i}.txt', 'r') as f:
      # Use the text from the file as the caption
      caption = f.read()

  # Post the image and use the text from the file as the caption
  bot.upload_photo(f'generated-images/image{i}.jpg', caption=caption)

  # Add a delay between requests
  time.sleep(200)
except:
  print('Error')
finally:
  bot.logout()
  print('logging out')

# Log out of Instagram
bot.logout()
```

It logged into my account successfully with no errors, but when it tries to post the images it gives the '429 error'...

Comment: It means you sent too many requests in too short a time, just like it says. Send your requests more slowly.

Comment: Is time.sleep(200) to fast??!

Comment: @MattDMo So is 200 too fast? if so if i changed it to something bigger would it work or am i blacklisted for a while?

Comment: I have tried changing the delay to bigger numbers but i keep getting the same error. @MattDMo

Comment: @OrbitalMartian Depends on how many requests you're sending. Instagram's rate limit is 200 requests per hour, although it's unclear how they enforce it. They could actually be enforcing it as 200 requests per hour, but they could also be enforcing it as 3 requests per minute. Regardless, if you don't want to upgrade to a business account, the solution would likely be to just slow it down until it stops complaining.

Comment: @Jesse I have an instagram business account actually and i am only making it autopost 10 images that have random text on them (this was just an example to see if it works) and the description is taken from a text file that has the characters in the image that have been generated. and it is only posting them every 200 seconds. I am not sure whats going on if maybe it's instabot or what.

Comment: @OrbitalMartian It's possible that it's a problem with the library. It may not even be a problem, maybe the call is just performing more requests than you're aware of. If not, it's likely an issue Instagram will have to work with you on.

Comment: @Jesse Hmm is there a way to log every time a request is sent to instagram so i can debug whats sending these requests?

Comment: @OrbitalMartian I'm not familiar with the instabot library (or Python at all for that matter), so I'm not sure if it provides a way to increase the log level. One way I have done things similar to that in the past though is just pulling up Wireshark and filtering by HTTP requests.

Comment: @Jesse ah ! thats ok no problem! i want to thank you for giving your help anyway

Comment: @Jesse I imported the logging module and this is my output: `DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): i.instagram.com:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://i.instagram.com:443 "POST /api/v1/accounts/get_prefill_candidates/ HTTP/1.1" 429 77
DEBUG:instabot version: 0.117.0:POST to endpoint: accounts/get_prefill_candidates/ returned response: <Response [429]>
DEBUG:instabot version: 0.117.0:Responsecode indicates error; response content: b'{"message":"Please wait a few minutes before you try again.","status":"fail"}'`

Comment: @OrbitalMartian Then yeah it looks like something you'll probably have to talk with Instagram support about. Can't really do much on your end if the server isn't accepting your requests.

Comment: @Jesse well thats a bummer... wish there was another way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding a delay then waiting until the next day, because the first time I ran the code apparently I sent way too many requests in a day.